# How to set the path of velocity templates?

Tags: scriptella

I try to make a report with scriptella and velocity. There is only one example with velocity in the scriptella distribution. There, the header and footer, are the current path. But how I can set up particular path with templates?

@ejboy, thank you for your replay.

I have two problems with the velocity driver. The first is how can I set url param in velocity connection definition as variable. I have a query like "SELECT * FROM table" and for each record I have to make a report in a separate file with the name connected with e.g. id of the record.

The second problem is with the path for the "header.vm" and "footer.vm" files. In my project (I use maven) my etl.xml file is under src/main/resources/scriptella and the header and footer could be in the same directory. Where can I set this path in etl.xml (or in a properties file which I can include).

Regards,
Jacek

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you want to achieve or provide an example of the script.

Comment: I have two problems with the velocity driver. The first is how can I set url param in velocity connection definition as variable. I have a query like "SELECT * FROM table" and for each record I have to make a report in a separate file with the name connected with e.g. id of the record.

The second problem is with the path for the "header.vm" and "footer.vm" files. In my project (I use maven) my etl.xml file is under src/main/resources/scriptella and the header and footer could be in the same directory. Where can I set this path in etl.xml (or in a properties file which I can include).